# StreamReader to Read Range of lines

Tags: c#, streamreader

Lets say I have a File and want to read the lines, it is:

```
   while( !streamReader.EndOfStream ) {
        var line = streamReader.ReadLine( );
   }
```

How do I read only a range of lines?
Like readlines from 10 to 20 only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq* without any reader:

```
  var lines = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyFile.txt")
    .Skip(10)  // skip first 10 lines 
    .Take(10); // take next 20 - 10 == 10 lines

  ...

  foreach(string line in lines) {
    ... 
  }
```

In case you *have to* use the reader, you can implement something like this

```
   // read top 20 lines...
   for (int i = 0; i < 20 && !streamReader.EndOfStream; ++i) {
     var line = streamReader.ReadLine();

     if (i < 10) // ...and skip first 10 of them
       continue;

     //TODO: put relevant code here
   }
```

Comment: the linq approach is much more elegant but i would get rid of the `var lines =..` and go straight in a loop `foreach(string line in File.Readlines...`

Comment: It is more elegant, but it reads the *entire* file into memory first, doesn't it? This may not be a good idea for larger files...

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: No! `.ReadLines` is not `.ReadAllLines` (please, notice `All`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - yeap my thoughts exactly